# How to add a condition in terraform iam policy? based on some value

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam

Hi I have declared my local variables as below,

```
locals {
  incoming_messages_queue = local.production == 1 ? 
["${aws_sqs_queue.my_queue1.arn}",
  "$"{aws_sqs_queue.my_queue2.arn}] : 
["${aws_sqs_queue.my_queue1.arn}]
}
```

Now based on the environment i.e only if production then i want to create a policy with allowing both the queues or else allow only one queue in the policy as below,

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "myservice_service_messaging" {
  role = aws_iam_role.myservice_service.name

  policy = <<POLICY
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
              "sns:CreateTopic",
               "sns:Publish"
             ],
    },
    {
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Action": [
               "sqs:GetQueueUrl",
               "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
               "sqs:DeleteMessage",
               "sqs:ChangeMessageVisibility"
       ],
       "Resource": "${local.incoming_messages_queue}"  #==> How to handle here based on condition
    },
    .................
    POLICY

}
```

Basically if the contition is true i want to add more than one resource in the policy and if the condition is false i want to add only one resource in the policy . I tried for loop as well its not working under the policy. Can someone please explain me how I can approach a solution for this?

Comment: Are you asking how to convert a HCL2 list to a JSON string list? You would just use the `jsonencode` function.

Comment: i am not using jsonencode , as when i tried it I got the below error "Duplicate resource "aws_iam_role_policy" configuration"  . This error is not happening when I use policy = <<POLICY method.

Comment: Converting HCL2 to JSON would not cause a duplicate declaration error.

Answer (score 0):

Generating JSON by string concatenation (which is what string templates do) is fraught with challenges to get correct syntax, because JSON is very sensitive to use of punctuation.

For that reason, I (and [the Terraform docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/templatefile.html#generating-json-or-yaml-from-a-template)) recommend always generating JSON using [the `jsonencode` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/jsonencode.html) instead, so that you can focus on generating the appropriate data structure and let Terraform be the one to worry about representing that value using correct JSON grammar.

When you use `jsonencode` you can write normal Terraform expressions in its argument, so you can use a conditional expression directly inline:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "myservice_service_messaging" {
  role = aws_iam_role.myservice_service.name

  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Effect = "Allow"
        Action = [
          "sns:CreateTopic",
          "sns:Publish",
        ]
      },
      {
        Effect = "Allow"
        Action = [
          "sqs:GetQueueUrl",
          "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
          "sqs:DeleteMessage",
          "sqs:ChangeMessageVisibility",
        ]
        Resource = (
          local.production == 1 ? 
          [aws_sqs_queue.my_queue1.arn, aws_sqs_queue.my_queue2.arn] :
          [aws_sqs_queue.my_queue1.arn]
        )
      },
    ]
  })
}
```

If you'll need that list of `Resource` ARNs elsewhere in your module then you can still factor it out into a local value if you like. In that case, you'd write:

```
        Resource = local.incoming_messages_queue
```

(Though, since it's a list, it would be more idiomatic to give it a plural name, like `local.incoming_message_queues`.)